# JDBC connection String in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

i want to migrate my applicaztion in aws,

i have setup my env. using elastic beanstalk.

in current version of my application, it runs OK locally, i setup the connection with this simple code:

in web.xml i have defined the resource:

```
<resource-ref> 
     <description> Resource reference to a factory for java.sql.Connection instances that may be used for talking to a particular database that is configured in the <Context> configuration for the web application. </description> 
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> 
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
</resource-ref>
```

then in config.xml i defined the resource

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="utente1" password="utente1" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nazioni?autoReconnect=true" />
```

now i'm able to get the connection in this way

```
/* JNDI query to locate the DataSource object */ 
Context initContext = new InitialContext(); 
Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env") ; 

// JNDI standard naming root 
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");

/* Ask DataSource for a connection */ 
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

now my question is: can i hard code the connection string in my config.xml or it is better to use System.getProperty("JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING")? if so, how i can set the connection string when tomcat is loaded ?

thanks, Loris

Answer (score 1):

[Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/) mentioning support for Ant-style variable substitution:

> Apache Ant-style variable substitution is supported; a system property
>   with the name propname may be used in a configuration file using the
>   syntax ${propname}. All system properties are available including
>   those set using the -D syntax, those automatically made available by
>   the JVM and those configured in the
>   $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

It means that if you define a property within `.ebextensions/<environment-name>.config` such as:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING
    value: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nazioni?autoReconnect=true
```

Then you should be able to reference that property in the configuration files:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="utente1" password="utente1" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="{JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING}" />
```

The approach has at least two benefits over hardcoded:

1. The value can be changed manually in AWS Beanstalk Console on a running instance
2. The value can be changed programmatically on a running instance

Answer (score 0):

Better go with XML configuration Becasue most of the application when moved from one Environment to another.There will be change in XML probably so XML is better from my Experience.

Also you can use property file but which helps most of the time when you want some property which is to be changed very often like lables not like configuration based things DB Connection String,SMTP,etc.

The Name of WEB.XML is Deployment descriptor becasue at the time deployment which is useful to load details about Applications based on the different environment.

Comment: so you think that it is better to hard code the connection string in config.xml?

Comment: not thinking, thats what most of the projects ,we have done.Because based on environment xml will be configured most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is best NOT to hard-code connection string information within your application (or other similar application configuration). Ideally you want to externalize application configuration so that your application to be portable between environments.

In the case of Elastic Beanstalk, you could deploy the same application WAR in different Beanstalk environments at the same time (perhaps a QA and a PROD environment) and if you hard-code the connection string then both WAR files would be pointing to the same DB instance.

Similarly, you may need to change the connection string at some point, maybe because your DB instance name changed, and if you hard-code the connection string then you would have to rebuild and deploy a new JAR.

If you use the JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING configuration provided by Elastic Beanstalk and read these in at runtime, then you can easily change the connection string using the Elastic Beanstalk console or API, and you can also maintain portability for a single WAR between different environments.